# Inherit properties from a node with relationship to another node to its child in neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

Inherit properties from all the parents.

Consider I have a graph with below format. I want the properties of a node (which will be in account node, if it has a relation) to be inherited by its child node. Assume Parent and child node relationship is maintained by [r:CHILD] and account information by [r2:ACCOUNT]. If node has more than one parent, it needs to inherit from all its parent with the first account  :

```
       (a0:ACCOUNT)<-[:HAS_ACCOUNT]-Morpheus
                                     \
         (a1:ACCOUNT)<-[:HAS_ACCOUNT]-Neo
                                       \
                                       alpha    
                                        \ 
                                       gamma    beta - [:HAS_ACCOUNT]->(a2:ACCOUNT)
                                          \    /
                                            A 
                                          /   \
            (a3:ACCOUNT)<-[:HAS_ACCOUNT]-B     C
                                       /  \   /  \
                                      D    E  F   G
```

I want to extract the data from the above graph something like this:

**Problem: Given a node, get all its children and also its account (if it has account , e.g: see node B) or its inherited account information. AccountID is part of account node**

**Consider input is node A**

**OUTPUT:**

```
|Node | CurrentNode|     Account   |Inherited_Account|
 - - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - - 
|  A  |    A       |     -         |   a1.accountID ,| 
|     |            |               |   a2.accountID  |
 - - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - - 
|  A  |    B       |  a3.accountID |        -        | 
 - - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - - 
|  A  |    D       |               |    a3.accountID | 
 - - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - - 
|  A  |    E       |               |    a3.accountID | 
 - - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - -
|  A  |    C       |               |   a1.accountID ,| 
|     |            |               |   a2.accountID  |
 - - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - - 
|  A  |    F       |               |   a1.accountID ,| 
|     |            |               |   a2.accountID  |
 - - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - - 
|  A  |    G       |               |   a1.accountID ,| 
|     |            |               |   a2.accountID  |
 - - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - -
```

This was my cypher to retrive that I came up with, gets me all the accounts of all the parents. It doesnt work sometimes

```
MATCH (node:Person{personID:"A"})
MATCH (account:ACCOUNT)
MATCH p =(parent:Person)-[:CHILD*1..]->(node)
where (parent)-[:HAS_ACCOUNT]->(account)
UNWIND RELATIONSHIPS(p) AS rel 
WITH p, account, COUNT(DISTINCT rel) AS nRoutes 
RETURN account,p, nRoutes 
ORDER BY nRoutes
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by how inheritance is supposed to work. From your example of nodes B, D, and E, it looks like you want the closest account (either your own, or inherited from the closest parent). But for node A, it looks like beta's account should be closest. Even if beta didn't exist, then it looks like it should only grab Neo's account as the closest parent account, and not include Morpheus's account, which is one node further. Can you clarify?

Comment: In case of B,D and E.., B has account . So that will be passed on to D and E. Suppose, if B did not have an account, it needs to get from A (as A is the only parent of B) .. 
In case of node A, it has two parents. and it doesn't have an account, so it gets the account from both of its parents.
If node A has an account, that will be passed on to its children.
If node A doesnt have account and If beta doesnt exist, it should get account from Neo (and not Morpheus)
If beta exists, it has to get Beta and also from Neo (as node A has two parents now - gamma and beta).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I confused a2 with a0 when reading the table, on second reading the expected output looks fine, though you may want to make sure a2 is on the :ACCOUNT node and not the relationship.

Comment: Can a single node only have one attached ACCOUNT, or can it have multiple?

Comment: Also, if C had another parent, delta, with an account a4, what should its inherited accounts be? a1, a2, and a4?

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/92359/inversefalcon . Exactly!!. If c had another parent, delta with a4, it should inherit a1,a2,and a4. Also, You are right: a single node can have multiple account and yes.. I am assuming a2 is on node.. not on relationship

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one.

A pure Cypher solution exists, but it's a complicated query and requires some potentially heavy filtering to weed out paths to account-holding nodes that are beyond closer account-holding nodes along the same path.

However, I've found a better alternate using Cypher and [APOC's path expander](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths), plus some pre-processing of adding a label to nodes that are account holders.

APOC's path expander has a means of expanding while respecting a label filter, and there is a means to define a label which should prune any further traversal, but be included as a solution. We'll use this to limit our expansion when getting account-holding ancestors for nodes.

Here's a creation query to recreate the graph in your example (though I'm labeling non-ACCOUNT nodes as :Node):

```
// create inherited account graph
create (morpheus:Node{name:'Morpheus'})
create (neo:Node{name:'Neo'})
create (alpha:Node{name:'alpha'})
create (gamma:Node{name:'gamma'})
create (beta:Node{name:'beta'})

create (A:Node{name:'A'})
create (B:Node{name:'B'})
create (C:Node{name:'C'})
create (D:Node{name:'D'})
create (E:Node{name:'E'})
create (F:Node{name:'F'})
create (G:Node{name:'G'})

create (morpheus)-[:CHILD]->(neo)
create (neo)-[:CHILD]->(alpha)
create (alpha)-[:CHILD]->(gamma)
create (gamma)-[:CHILD]->(A)
create (beta)-[:CHILD]->(A)
create (A)-[:CHILD]->(B)
create (A)-[:CHILD]->(C)
create (B)-[:CHILD]->(D)
create (B)-[:CHILD]->(E)
create (C)-[:CHILD]->(F)
create (C)-[:CHILD]->(G)

create (morpheus)-[:HAS_ACCOUNT]->(a0:ACCOUNT{name:'a0'})
create (neo)-[:HAS_ACCOUNT]->(a1:ACCOUNT{name:'a1'})
create (beta)-[:HAS_ACCOUNT]->(a2:ACCOUNT{name:'a2'})
create (B)-[:HAS_ACCOUNT]->(a3:ACCOUNT{name:'a3'})
```

Next, we label account-holding nodes.

```
MATCH (acc:ACCOUNT)
WITH acc
MATCH (acc)<-[:HAS_ACCOUNT]-(holder)
SET holder:ACCOUNT_HOLDER
```

Once that's in place, we can use the following query to get your desired output:

```
// parameterize this in your own query
with 'A' as nodeName
match (node:Node{name:nodeName})-[r:CHILD*0..]->(currentNode)
with node, currentNode, size(r) as distance
optional match (currentNode)-[:HAS_ACCOUNT]->(acc)
with node, currentNode, distance, collect(acc) as accounts
// we now have all child nodes of the given node and their accounts, if they exist.

// this expands up from each currentNode, 
// stopping each expansion at the closest ACCOUNT_HOLDER node
call apoc.path.expand(currentNode, '<CHILD', '/ACCOUNT_HOLDER', -1, -1)
yield path
with node, currentNode, distance, accounts, last(nodes(path)) as holder
// get the account for each holder, 
// but only if the current doesn't have its own accounts
optional match (holder)-[:HAS_ACCOUNT]->(acc)
where size(accounts) = 0
with node, currentNode, accounts, collect(acc) as inherited, distance
order by distance asc
return node, currentNode, accounts, inherited
```

However, note that even with this approach, the query will not build up and reuse solutions (for example, once we've found the account-holding ancestors for node A, that solution is not referenced or reused when we have to get the account-holding ancestors for nodes, C, F, or G). You may want to consider a custom procedure to perform this complicated matching operation in code rather than Cypher for maximum efficiency.

Comment: Thanks InverseFalcon. I was busy and couldn't try this out. I will try my hands on this in couple of days